# Why can't alignment by Align widget?

Tags: flutter

I need to align "Scan check" in the center of Text widget. I try widget `Align` but it not help.

snippet:

```
 Widget _createScanCheckContainer() {
    return new Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN),
        height: 56.0,
        color: Color(Constants.COLOR_PRIMARY),
        child: Row(children: [
          new Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                "Scan check",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 19.0, color: Colors.white),
              ))
        ]));
  }
```

Here result.

[image]

Why **Scan check** is not on the center?

Comment: in this case `Row` is redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the row center align all its children horizontally.

```
Widget _createScanCheckContainer() {
    return new Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN),
        height: 56.0,
        color: Color(Constants.COLOR_PRIMARY),
        child: Row(children: [
          new Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                "Scan check",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 19.0, color: Colors.white),
              ))
        ], mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Align here, because its size **is determined in accordance** with its child.

Therefore it does **not expand to Row's width**.
[image]

You should use [mainAxisAlignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row/mainAxisAlignment.html) property for Row to align your Text

```dart
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
    children: [
          Text(
            "Scan check",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0, color: Colors.white),
          )
        ]
)
```

[image]